# Kotlin dsl gradle, how call and execute function inside .kt with custom task

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, dsl

I have and application that have

```
fun main() {}
```

inside test/kotlin/com.company/LocalApplication.kt

I use that to run in localhost for example with IntelliJ I just do click on run that function to start my application.

what do that function inside test its generate a custom args config for localhost and after that call the real main/com.company/Application.kt

so i want to create a task for kotlin dsl gradle in the build.gradle.kts that do exactly the same that Intellij do when i click manually on run on that fun main()

for example in terminal do this:

```
gradle localhost
```

and that command call the fun main() {} inside test/kotlin/com.company/LocalApplication.kt and start my application with the localhost config.

thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume this very basic application `App.kt`:

```
package com.company

class App {
    val greeting: String
        get() {
            return "Hello world."
        }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(App().greeting)
}
```

You can make use of the [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task type.

Define a custom task of type `JavaExec`:

```
tasks.register<JavaExec>("localhost") {
    classpath = sourceSets.test.get().runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.company.LocalApplication"
}
```

You'll then need to update your `LocalApplication.kt` to use `@file:JvmName`:

```
@file:JvmName("LocalApplication")
package com.company

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(App().greeting)
}
```

Then running the task in my terminal produces:

```
$ ./gradlew localhost

> Task :localhost
Hello world.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

There are many more options of the `JavaExec` task, read the docs for more information.

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#handling-signature-clashes-with-jvmname

Tested with:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-01-24 22:30:24 UTC
Revision:     a8c3750babb99d1894378073499d6716a1a1fa5d

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          11.0.6 (AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.6+10)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.3 x86_64
```